# Does "Eine Sprache lässt sich sprechen" make sense?

Tags: passive

"sich lassen" + Infinitiv is one of the alternatives to Modales Passiv.
We can say

> Das Problem **wird** gelöst.
> Das Problem **kann** gelöst **werden**.
> Das Problem ist lös**bar**.
> Das Problem **lässt** **sich** lösen.

And other alternatives which I have not listed.
But with "sprechen", every alternative seems wrong to native speakers I have asked:

> Deutsch **wird** gesprochen.
> Deutsch **kann** gesprochen **werden.**
> ? Deutsch ist sprech**bar.**
> ? Deutsch **lässt sich** sprechen.

Why do the alternatives not work? Does it have to do with semantic properties of the verb (like telic and such)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you another example (boiling eggs):

- Correct:

  > 1. Die Eier werden gekocht.
  > 2. Die Eier können gekocht werden.
- Grammatically correct but semantically weird:

  > 3. Die Eier sind kochbar.
  > 4. Die Eier lassen sich kochen.

The point is that #1 and #2 are about actions, but #3 and #4 are about properties:

The main verb in the sentences 1 and 2 is *kochen*. The other verbs in these sentences are there only for grammatical reasons, they do not add to the proposition<sup>1</sup> of the sentence (*werden* is an auxiliary verb and *können* is a modal verb). So both sentences describe eggs that are in boiling water. None of these sentences describes special properties of the eggs.

But sentences #3 and #4 describe properties.

The verb in #3 is *sind* (a form of *sein = to be*) which is a copula. Copulas a coupling-verbs that connect other things to the subject. Copulas do not describe actions like verbs normally do. Here it connects the adjective *kochbar = boilable* to the subject.

The verb in #4 is *lassen* which, when used together with a reflexive pronoun (here: *sich*), describes a possibility, but a possibility is a property, not an action. So the sentence #4 means roughly the same as #3.

In the sentences 3 and 4 you might be talking about eggs that still lay in the refrigerator or even about eggs that a chicken in a laboratory on the moon might lay in the year 2317. But you are not talking about eggs that here and now are in boiling water. (Unless the context explicitly indicates this.) And this generality is what makes these sentences a little bit weird.

Yes, sure, eggs are boilable. The sentences are not wrong. But anything can be boiled as long as it fits in a pot filled with boiling water. Shoes are boilable, butter knifes are boilable and even mobile phones are boilable. So why is it worth to mention that also eggs are boilable?

The sentences are grammatically correct, but this is not enough to be *really* correct. Also this sentence is grammatically correct, but it makes no sense: *»My left hat sits in the basement and knits petroleum.«* The sentences #3 and #4 are not of that extreme degree of nonsense as this example, but they still sound weird.

---

When we talk about a language that can be spoken, then the two sentences that describe actions perfectly make sense. But the two sentences that are about properties of German are as weird as those about boilable eggs. Yes, German is speakable. But any language is speakable. That is what defines a language. When you explicitly say that German is speakable, then you also communicate that other languages might not be speakable.

Imagine the dinner buffet of a very large hotel: You see hundreds of different dishes and want to decide which one to eat, and then someone from the hotel staff comes up to you and whispers: *"The cheesecake is eatable".* - What do you think then about the rest of the buffet?

---

So, what is different with the solvable problem?

We all know that there are many problems that are not solvable. Therefore, it makes sense to talk not only about the process of solving in the case of this specific problem, but also about the solvability of this specific problem as opposed to the solvability of problems in the general case.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The proposition is what that makes an expression true or false. One can argue, that modal verbs like *können* also modify the proposition, but discussing this is beyond the topic of this question.</sub>